# How to progress my 5e Barbarian

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, barbarian

I'm currently playing a barbarian in a new 5e campaign. Rolled a variant human, started with sentinel. My Str is 18 and con is 16. We are about to hit level 4 in our next session and I was kinda wavering about if I wanted to put my con up to 18 **or** just max out my Str to 20.

I'm not the main tank in the party, so I'm more of the bruiser but I don't want to drag my party down.

Comment: I believe the question as posed is primarily opinion based. What exactly is your concern here? An ability score choice is hardly a reason to "drag your party down"

Comment: Which totem did you choose, or are you a berserker?  Your feat is Sentinel.  What is your role in the party if not main tank? (With an 18/18 or with a 20/16 you will not be dragging your party down).

Comment: What other characters do you have in the party, and what role do they expect you to take? Is any member of the party particularly dependent on your barbarian in any way? Are you worried your choice will hinder your party in particular types of encounter?

Comment: Reminder: comments are for clarifying content, [not posting small or incomplete answers](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/6534). Prior comments containing answers have been removed.